# Error during web scraping in R using Selector Gadget

Tags: r, rvest

I hope you are all doing well.
I am facing an error during web scraping in R using the Selector Gadget Tool where when I am selecting the data using the tool on the Coursera website, the no. of values it shows is correct (10). But when I copy that particular CSS code in R and run it, it's showing 18 names in the list. Please if anyone can help me with this.  Here is a screenshot of the selector gadget output:

[image: This is the Bachelor's degree data of Coursera]

And here is what gets returned in R when I scrape that css selector:

[image: The variable name is bd_coursera]

Comment: What is the desired output from the scraping?  There are 10 names and 8 due dates.  If you did `bd_coursera_names[-grep("\\d{4}", bd_coursera_names)]` you should end up with the 10 non-date-containing elements from your vector.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The desired output I want is 10 names without 8 due dates. When I am selecting the names from the selector gadget tool, it shows all the correct names selected (10)  without the due dates (8). But when I am applying the same CSS code in the RStudio, then the output it gives is 18 names (10 names and 8 due dates). I'm very confused about this thing.

Comment: And sir can you please explain the code as well? It literally solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The rendered content seen via a browser is not exactly the same as that returned by an XHR request (rvest). This is because a browser can run JavaScript to update content.

Inspect the page source by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in browser on that webpage.

You can re-write your css selector list to match the actual html returned. One example would be as follows, which also removes the reliance on dynamic classes which change more frequently and would break your program more quickly.

```
library(rvest)

read_html("https://in.coursera.org/degrees/bachelors") |>
  html_elements('[data-e2e="degree-list"] div[class] > p:first-child') |>
  html_text2()
```

Learn about CSS selectors and operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors